# How to insert interactive map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use GoogleMap in my website :

```
           function InsertMap()
           {
               var map;
                var op = {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };                    
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('id'), op);
           }
```

I am calling this function on button click event. But my problem is that it insert a static map ( a single image ) instead of interactive map. I tried a `IsStaticMap : false` also but its not working and when i did that it shows nothing neither static nor interactive. Help me out !

Comment: Is `IsStaticMap` a documented `MapOptions` property?

Comment: No, while searching i found this property and i tried, but not working

Comment: I copied your code and it works fine. You must have some other error. A link to a live page would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an implementation using jQuery which might help you. The source code and demo are included!

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/create-an-interactive-google-map-widget-with-a-list-filter-and-a-map-helper-class/

Answer (score -1):

This is what I usually use, works good! You can edit it as per your requirements.

```
  <iframe
    width="425"
    height="350"
    frameborder="0"
    scrolling="no"
    marginheight="0"
    marginwidth="0"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=San%2BFrancisco%2C%2BCalifornia(HEY%21)@37.774930,-122.419416&ie=UTF8&z=12&t=m&iwloc=addr&output=embed">
  </iframe>

<br>

<table
  width="425"
  cellpadding="0"
  cellspacing="0"
  border="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="left">
      <small><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=San%2BFrancisco%2C%2BCalifornia(HEY%21)@37.774930,-122.419416&ie=UTF8&z=12&t=m&iwloc=addr">View Larger Map</a></small></td><td align="right"><small><a href="http://www.github.com/dtx">my git!</a></small></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tKYQu/)

Comment: hmm, i realized later that this was a JS question. Anyways, hope it helps you or someone else. :)

Comment: lol this did not deserve a downvote. even the right answer is downvoted. sigh.